# C++ pulling first letter of variable value instead of first item in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I've got a humdinger of a problem that's making my code all cattywampus!

I've attempted to simplify the code down to what is relevant to the problem.  Basically I have one string type array containing items (newArray) and a second of array containing inventory (inventoryItems).  inentoryItems contains all integers, a few rows and 2 columns.  the first column represents a different array, and the second column represents the item from that array.  The whole purpose of this is so that I can reference the int. in the inventory array to a string title of that item.  For this example, the first column represents the array inventoryItems.  Through the process i've created, the end result is that I output the second letter of the name of the array instead of the second item in the array.

```
int itemCount = 2;
int someFunction() {
string newArray[3] = 
    {   "one",
        "two",
        "three"
    }
}


int displayInventory()
{
    int pos1;
    int pos2;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++ )
    {
        string tableName;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                pos1 = inventoryItems[i][j];
                tableName = findTable(pos1);
            }
            else if (j == 1)
            {
                pos2 = inentoryItems[i][j];
                cout << tableName[pos2] << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

string findTable(int table)
{
    if (table == 0)
    {
        selection = "newArray";
    }
    return selection;
}
```

Comment: This code is riddled with simple errors, is unnecessarily verbose and doesn't give enough context for your problem.  Please correct or it'll be held.

Comment: one easy-to-spot problem is newArray[2] with 3 members.

Comment: That's definitely possible.  I attempted to simplify it so I probably made a few mistakes. What does "held" mean?  This is my first post here.

Comment: @picardrulez put on hold. essentially blocked

Comment: and "newArray" does have quotes, just as I mentioned on Ademo's page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've got quotes around newArray in the statement `selection = "newArray";`. get rid of the quotes. I'm assuming all the other errors are due to hastily extracting a portion of the code for illustration.

Comment: That did it!  That and the fact that I was referencing an array that was accidentally out of scope.

Comment: I made the changes in the post to reflect that.